# "setSupportActionBar(toolbar)" inside FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

How do I access `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar)` inside `FragmentActivity`?
I can't access it inside `FragmentActivity`

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
setSupportActionBar( toolbar);
```

Comment: need to extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity

Comment: Maybe that's not an option. I have a need of FragmentActivity and Toolbar in the same activity.

Answer (score 28):

With the latest version of the support library you should make your Activity extend `AppCompatActivity` as `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated.

It provides the same functionality as your ActionBarActivity previously did. You shouldn't need to make any further changes.

Comment: use this => ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar( toolbar);

Comment: @RajanMaurya to my understanding that is the same as simply calling `setSupportActionBar( toolbar);`

Answer (score 21):

You can just extend your class with `AppCompatActivity`, since `AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity` internally. Also,  `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

Use ActionBarActivity from support library, ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity, So that you can get SupportFragmentManager and set toolbar as actionbar

Ex:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
 setSupportActionBar( toolbar);

 FragmentManager manager=this.getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Comment: With latest version of support library one should use `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 5):

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`

```
public class AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AppCompatCallback, SupportParentable, DelegateProvider
```

you can use `AppCompatActivity` instead

Comment: Don't you think this answer can be a comment to @zero answer instead?

Answer (score 3):

If your class extends `FragmentActivity`

and if the toolbar is inside the layout you used, it will be set by default. To access it simply do

`(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this methods your activity **need to extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity**

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
setSupportActionBar( toolbar);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I want Customized ToolBar in Map... So if I use ActionBarActivity App Crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `ViewPager` to add fragments, you can extend `AppCompatActivity`, it also works. (Often, we extend `FragmentActivity`, but after that `setSupportActionBar`( toolbar) doesn't work)
So, we can extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of extending `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

For `FragmenrtActivity`, you should look into `FragmentTabHost`, and to add tabs simply:

```
tab = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tab.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
tab.addTab(tabs.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("TAB1"), tab1.class, null);
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using setSupportActionBar use setActionBar
Eg:

```
android.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);    
setActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: it only allows for API 21.